# Java ads system

Tags: java, ads, banner, openx

Are there any good open source ads (banner rotation) systems for Java (like OpenX for PHP)?

Comment: Why would you want that exactly?

Comment: Because we have a site running on Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just use OpenX integrated with Apache as a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Andrey, you might be interested to take a look at AdServerBeans MyAds (http://www.adserverbeans.com)

It's open source and it's written in Java, Flex, SQL stored procedures.